# Keras Sequential model trains on GPU slowly (not any faster than CPU)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, gpu

This is from the book Deep Learning with R by Francois Chollet, Ch 6.3.

I can successfully train NN's on 2 gpus with other models, such as covnets. When I try to do it with a sequential model, the GPU's train slower than the CPU.

I monitor the GPU's, and they are in fact running and being utilized. I also tried increasing the batch size by several multiples, but no such luck.

I'm wondering what the possible bottlenecks could be. Reproducible code is below as an R notebook. I only changed the last chunk where multi_gpu_model() is used.

````
```{r, eval=FALSE, echo=TRUE}
dir.create("~/Downloads/jena_climate", recursive = TRUE)
download.file(
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip",
  "~/Downloads/jena_climate/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip"
)
unzip(
  "~/Downloads/jena_climate/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip",
  exdir = "~/Downloads/jena_climate"
)
```

```{r, results='hide'}
library(tibble)
library(readr)

data_dir <- "~/Downloads/jena_climate"
fname <- file.path(data_dir, "jena_climate_2009_2016.csv")
data <- read_csv(fname)
```


```{r}
data <- data.matrix(data[,-1])
```

```{r}
train_data <- data[1:200000,]
mean <- apply(train_data, 2, mean)
std <- apply(train_data, 2, sd)
data <- scale(data, center = mean, scale = std)
```

```{r}
generator <- function(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
                      shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 128, step = 6) {
  if (is.null(max_index))
    max_index <- nrow(data) - delay - 1
  i <- min_index + lookback
  function() {
    if (shuffle) {
      rows <- sample(c((min_index+lookback):max_index), size = batch_size)
    } else {
      if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
        i <<- min_index + lookback
      rows <- c(i:min(i+batch_size, max_index))
      i <<- i + length(rows)
    }

    samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows), 
                                lookback / step,
                                dim(data)[[-1]]))
    targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows)))

    for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
      indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback, rows[[j]], 
                     length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
      samples[j,,] <- data[indices,]
      targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay,2]
    }            

    list(samples, targets)
  }
}
```

```{r}
lookback <- 1440
step <- 6
delay <- 144
batch_size <- 128

train_gen <- generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = 1,
  max_index = 200000,
  shuffle = TRUE,
  step = step, 
  batch_size = batch_size
)

val_gen = generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = 200001,
  max_index = 300000,
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

test_gen <- generator(
  data,
  lookback = lookback,
  delay = delay,
  min_index = 300001,
  max_index = NULL,
  step = step,
  batch_size = batch_size
)

# This is how many steps to draw from `val_gen`
# in order to see the whole validation set:
val_steps <- (300000 - 200001 - lookback) / batch_size

  # This is how many steps to draw from `test_gen`
# in order to see the whole test set:
test_steps <- (nrow(data) - 300001 - lookback) / batch_size
```

```{}
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_gru(units = 32, input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]])) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

parallel_model <- multi_gpu_model(model, gpus = 2)

parallel_model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  loss = "mae"
)

history <- parallel_model %>% fit_generator(
  train_gen,
  steps_per_epoch = 500,
  epochs = 20,
  validation_data = val_gen,
  validation_steps = val_steps
)
```
````